# Succinct way to print using multiple getter methods - Java

Tags: java

I have quite a few getter methods in a class and I need to print the return of those getters (Just one and not all of them at once). I need to be able to do this with one `print()` method but I am not sure how to do this. Is there a way to dynamically call another method and then print the return of that method?

Here are a couple of getter methods:

```
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return this.studentEmail;
    }

    public Integer getAge()
    {
        return this.studentAge;
    }
```

Here is what I am wanting to do:

```
public void print(???)
{
    System.out.println(theGetterMethod);
}
```

I know that I can create a bunch of print methods but I need to be able to do this with one method.

Comment: You can tackle it by using `Sytem.out.println ("E-mail: " + ...getEmail(), " Age: " + ...getAge());` If you want to go *overkill* you can use reflection.

Comment: @Emz Sorry, I should have mentioned that I only need to print one thing at at time and not use all of the getter methods, but just one of the getter methods.

Comment: Normally the `toString()` method prints all fields.

Comment: If you want to use one specific getter why not simply use `System.out.println(`*thatGetter()*`);`? Even if you do manage to solve it dynamically to invoke the right method with your print (and yes it is possible, though I see no reason as to why in this case) it will be about the same coding.

Comment: @markspace, no `toString` prints `getClass() + "@" + getHash()` default.

Comment: I agree with @Emz, I don't understand why you need to write a print method to dynamically access a getter, instead of just accessing that getter right away. Instead of `public void print(???) {
    System.out.println(theGetterMethod);
}`, why just not call `System.out.println(getX())` directly?

Comment: @Emz Here is what I am supposed to do: `print() to print specific student data (e.g., student ID, first name, last name) using accessors (i.e., getters)`. It looks like I can just create print methods for each of them and not do it dynamically. The way I read it, it seems ambiguous. If you want to make an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html. This is a not a straight forward action: You will even have to compile your code different, implement some extra code yourself, and then you can do this all over your code.

Comment: @Emz If you actually override the `toString()` method, that's what I mean.  The usual way is to dump out all fields so they can be viewed.

Comment: How is the student data stored? If it is stored in let's say a `HashMap<K,V>;` I can understand, then you can print based on `K` by invoking `.get(K)`

Comment: @Emz It's stored in an ArrayList<Student>. Please see my previous comment. I think you were correct with your first comment and it can be an answer.

Comment: I've added it as an answer with some more to it than my short comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As asked by the OP:**

"*I think you were correct with your first comment and it can be an answer.*"

**From:**

"*You can tackle it by using Sytem.out.println ("E-mail: " + ...getEmail(), " Age: " + ...getAge()); If you want to go overkill you can use reflection.*"

Meaning instead of having a seperate `print()` method you will instead be invoking the right accessor for the value you want to print.

This is one of reasons why you use accessors in the place, as now you are exposing the fields without any risk of having the user change them.

*You can still change on underlying `Object`s apart from `String` as it is immutable.*

Answer (score 1):

You can call methods dynamically based on their name by using reflection.

In this example I assume that each `Getter` follows a pattern and just pass over the property name that I want to print out:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Student {

    private String studentEmail = "MyEmail";
    private Integer studentAge = 20;

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.studentEmail;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return this.studentAge;
    }

    // Prints out a property based on the name
    public void print(String property) throws Exception {
        for (Method method : this.getClass().getMethods())
            if (method.getName().equals("get" + property))
                System.out.println(method.invoke(this, null));
    }

    // Prints out all properties with a getter
    public void print() throws Exception {
        for (Method method : this.getClass().getMethods())
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get"))
                System.out.println(method.invoke(this, null));
    }
}
```

And than call the method like that:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.print("Email");
s.print("Age");
```

Comment: I like this method.  Just to add to it, if you wanted to know what all of your getters were (presumably so you would know what getter results you could `print()`), you could just do a loop through the `Method` names with a `startsWith("get")`.